# error thrown while trying to do a group by

Tags: soql, community, sql, group-by

I'm trying to write a query that gives me the name of users and the total number of ids assigned to them.

Here I've `Daily_Task__c` a custom object with a lot of fields, here I'm trying to get the total number of cases assigned to a user and I'm trying the below query

```
SELECT count(id), User_Name__c FROM Daily_Task__c group by User_Name__c
```

when I'm running this query I get the error as below.

> [object Object]: User_Name__c FROM Daily_Task__c group by User_Name__c ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:58 field 'User_Name__c' can not be grouped in a
>   query call

but when I do the below query it is working fine

```
SELECT id, User_Name__c FROM Daily_Task__c order by User_Name__c
```

it is showing the list of all the ids and users(sorted).

please let me know on where am I going wrong with the `group by` case and how can I fix it.

Here is what I see when I run `System.debug(Daily_Task__c.User_Name__c.getDescribe());` in my developer console.

> 00:32:47:018 USER_DEBUG
>   [1]|DEBUG|Schema.DescribeFieldResult[getByteLength=3900;getCalculatedFormula=Daily_Update__r.Ass_Usr___r.First_Name__c;getCompoundFieldName=null;getController=null;getDefaultValue=null;getDefaultValueFormula=null;getDigits=0;getFilteredLookupInfo=null;getInlineHelpText=null;getLabel=DE
>   Name;getLength=1300;getLocalName=User_Name__c;getMask=null;getMaskType=null;getName=User_Name__c;getPrecision=0;getReferenceTargetField=null;getRelationshipName=null;getRelationshipOrder=null;getScale=0;getSoapType=STRING;getSobjectField=User_Name__c;getType=STRING;isAccessible=true;isAggregatable=true;isAiPredictionField=false;isAutoNumber=false;isCalculated=true;isCascadeDelete=false;isCaseSensitive=false;isCreateable=false;isCustom=true;isDefaultedOnCreate=false;isDependentPicklist=false;isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;isDisplayLocationInDecimal=false;isEncrypted=false;isExternalId=false;isFilterable=true;isFormulaTreatNullNumberAsZero=true;isGroupable=false;isHighScaleNumber=false;isHtmlFormatted=false;isIdLookup=false;isNameField=false;isNamePointing=false;isNillable=true;isPermissionable=true;isQueryByDistance=false;isRestrictedDelete=false;isSearchPrefilterable=false;isSortable=true;isUnique=false;isUpdateable=false;isWriteRequiresMasterRead=false;]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The describe information you were able to extract shows

```
isGroupable=false
```

which is a proximate, if not very useful, answer. In this case, the real problem blocking you from using this field in a `GROUP BY` appears to be that it is a cross-object formula field:

```
Daily_Update__r.Ass_Usr___r.First_Name__c
```

The documentation on [`GROUP BY` Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_group_by_considerations.htm) does not make clear exactly which field types inherently are and are not groupable, but it makes some amount of naive sense to me that cross-object formula fields wouldn't be groupable - there'd certainly be a performance cost involved, at minimum.

As a simple illustration that this is the cause, I created a custom formula field `Account_Name__c` on `Contact`, with the formula `Account.Name`. Having done, so the query

```
SELECT count(Id) FROM Contact GROUP BY Account_Name__c
```

returns the same error you're seeing, despite that

```
SELECT count(Id) FROM Contact GROUP BY Account.Name
```

is perfectly legal. Since `Account.Name` is not encrypted, long text, rich text, or anything else fancy, it looks like the mere fact of being a cross-object formula makes the field non-groupable.

Edit: I've discovered that the conclusion above is incorrect, as detailed in [another answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235528/what-types-of-fields-are-groupable-in-a-soql-group-by-clause/235529#235529). It is not the cross-object nature of the formula field, but its type, that determines groupability. String formula fields are not groupable.