# Field 'PermissionsWorkplaceCommandCenter' can not be grouped in a query call

Tags: soql, profile, permission-sets, workbench

I am trying to get the value of `PermissionsWorkplaceCommandCenter` field per Profile in `PermissionSets` via Salesforce Workbench.

At first, I have this query:

[image]

But this results to following error:

[image]

I modified the query based on the error, so my second query turned out like this:

[image]

But another error occurs, which is kind of confusing.

[image]

I don't know what else is wrong, I just followed what the first query error suggested, but it just resulted to another error.

Hoping someone could help me correct this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What types of fields are groupable in a SOQL \`GROUP BY\` clause?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235528/what-types-of-fields-are-groupable-in-a-soql-group-by-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Certain field are not groupable (already answered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235528/what-types-of-fields-are-groupable-in-a-soql-group-by-clause/235529#235529) by @DavidReed). You may check this via Describe objects & field in apex. Or, you can check this from `Workbench` > `Info` > `Standard & Custom Objects` > Expand `Fields` & then the *specific field* > Check the `groupable` attribute. Sample screenshot given below for another field.

[image]

Comment: I see. But is there a way wherein I can group it via Profile's Name field only and just display the `PermissionsWorkplaceCommandCenter` for each? I think SOQL does not accept grouping unless I group it also by this field, which is kind of absurd because it is not groupable in the first place.

Comment: You may try a non-elegant solution proposed by @PeterKnolle [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/what-makes-a-field-not-groupable?noredirect=1&lq=1) i.e., create another groupable field and copy this field value using workflow rule.

Comment: I checked this one also. This surely does it but seems a bit overkill for a requirement that should be done through query in the first place. Looks like Salesforce needs to consider this. But thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: Agreed. It's a overkill for trivial business requirements, but then sorting the data and applying code logic over it would be too. Salesforce marks fields as not groupable for very specific reasons, so I'm not sure if they would consider marking this as groupable. If you are paid customer, check with the SF support if they can enable grouping for your org.