# SOQL aggregate query issue with number fields

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, limits, aggregateresult

> **I was trying built aggregate query on number field, Found an strange behaviour.**

Object Considered: **Campaign**

I have used Visual Code for execute SOQL for my analysis.

**Use Case 1:**

NumberOfContacts -> Standard Salsforce Number Field  : Number(9, 0)

sfdx force:data:soql:query --query **SELECT NumberOfContacts, COUNT(Id)  FROM Campaign GROUP BY NumberOfContacts**

Querying Data... done
NUMBEROFCONTACTS  COUNT(ID)
────────────────  ─────────
0                 1
Total number of records retrieved: 1.

**Use Case 2:**

NumberSent -> Standard Salsforce Number Field : Number(18, 0)

sfdx force:data:soql:query --query **SELECT NumberSent, COUNT(Id)  FROM Campaign GROUP BY NumberSent**

Querying Data... done
ERROR running force:data:soql:query:
COUNT(Id)  FROM Campaign GROUP BY NumberSent
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:54
field 'NumberSent' can not be grouped in a query call

**Use Case 3:**

TestNumberField__c -> Custom Number Field  : Number(9, 0)

sfdx force:data:soql:query --query **SELECT TestNumberField__c, COUNT(Id)  FROM Campaign GROUP BY TestNumberField__c**

Querying Data... done
ERROR running force:data:soql:query:
COUNT(Id)  FROM Campaign GROUP BY TestNumberField__c
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:69
field 'TestNumberField__c' can not be grouped in a query call

> Question is why i am able run aggregate query on number standard number field which has length of 9, and unable to do on custom number field and standard number field which has length 18.

**Is this a limitation of Salesforce ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain fields are not groupable. For number fields, they are groupable if they are standard and are integer deep at the API level. For all other numbers they are decimals and are not groupable.

Can see more in this other question's chosen answer: [What types of fields are groupable in a SOQL `GROUP BY` clause?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/235528/18269)