# Group By fails with invalid field - How to handle encrypted fields?

Tags: soql, encryption, aggregate, field-level-encryption, encrypt

I want to find every record that occurs at least two times. The result should be something like this

| MyLineItem__c | Type__c | ItemValueString__c | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | Boo | Booze | 2 |
| Yal | Bal | Jazz | 2 |
| Xul | Xal | Xray | 3 |

I tried this query

```
SELECT MyLineItem__c, Type__c, 
       ItemValueString__c, Count(Id)
FROM MyDetail__c 
WHERE 
     CreatedDate > 2024-01-20T00:00:00.000Z
GROUP BY
     MyLineItem__c, Type__c, ItemValueString__c
```

and got

> INVALID_FIELD [object Object]: MyLineItem__c , Type__c,
> ItemValueString__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:196 field
> 'ItemValueString__c' can not be grouped in a query call

The field `ItemValueString__c` is encrypted

[image: Custom Field Definition Edit]

Based on [What types of fields are groupable in a SOQL `GROUP BY` clause?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/235529/123400) i assume that the encryption is the cause for the error message.

### Questions

- How to handle encypted fields?
- What can be done to analyze these field?

Comment: You cannot use shield encrypted fields in WHERE, GROUP BY and ORDER BY. This is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_considerations_general.htm). You might consider adding a field to hold the hash of the data for the encrypted field and use that in your GROUP BY.

Comment: If your org has moved to Hyperforce, you can remove encryption on these fields as the entire (disk) volume is now encrypted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use shield encrypted fields in `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses. This is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_considerations_general.htm). You might consider adding a field to hold the hash of the data for the encrypted field and use that in your `GROUP BY`.

Since your `ItemValueString__c` field is a string, you can easily add a second field, like `ItemValueHash__c`, that is an integer. You would then include automation (through an apex trigger) that reacts when the `ItemValueString__c` is set or updated (so in `before insert` and `before update`):

```
for (MyDetail__c newRecord : Trigger.new) {
    MyDetail__c oldRecord = (Trigger.oldMap != null) ?
        Trigger.oldMap.get(newRecord.Id) :
        null;

    if (newRecord.ItemValueString__c != oldRecord?.ItemValueString__c) {
        newRecord.ItemValueHash__c = newRecord.ItemValueString__c.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can `GROUP BY ItemValueHash__c` instead. Other aspects of the query may require update too (such as not including the `ItemValueString__c` in the results).

Comment: Regarding `ItemValueHash__c` - do you know if hashCollisions are more likely to occur for shorter strings (`ABC`, `DEF`) compared to longer strings (`ABCDEFGHIJ`, `KLMNOPQRST`)?

Comment: With the assumption Salesforce use the Java string hash code algorithm (seems very likely to me), the length of a string **can** affect the likelihood of a hash collision, but (apparently) not in a significant or deterministic way. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518418/whats-behind-the-hashcode-method-for-string-in-java) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method-for-a-collection).